# Junit test spring controller mockMvc @ContextConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test

I'm writing my test cases with MockMvc. This is how my controller looks like:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/context/local-applicationContext-database.xml",
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-common.xml",
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-dao.xml",
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-service.xml",
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml",
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-aop.xml",
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-transaction.xml",
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/context/local-applicationContext-host.xml"
})

public class ControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
     this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }
```

But I am gettinG ApplicationContext errors:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean (the beans which are defines inside the above inluded conext files).

If I us e the same configuration with old approach (i.e without using MockMvc , it works)

Any suggestions what is wrong here?

full stack trace:

```
    Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@224a9e5] to prepare test instance [com.omgeo.ts.confirm.controller.profile.test.BTIImportProfileControllerTest@224a97f] [org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager:314]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-common.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodCachePointCut' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodCacheInterceptor' while setting bean property 'advice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodCacheInterceptor' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodCache' while setting bean property 'cache'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodCache' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'EHCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EHCacheManager' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cache/ehcache-config.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:454)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:786)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodCachePointCut' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodCacheInterceptor' while setting bean property 'advice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodCacheInterceptor' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodCache' while setting bean property 'cache'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodCache' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'EHCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EHCacheManager' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cache/ehcache-config.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:890)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodCacheInterceptor' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodCache' while setting bean property 'cache'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodCache' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'EHCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EHCacheManager' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cache/ehcache-config.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodCache' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'EHCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EHCacheManager' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cache/ehcache-config.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EHCacheManager' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-ehcache.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cache/ehcache-config.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cache/ehcache-config.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 81 more
```

Comment: We can only know that if you post your full stack trace. Maybe you have duplicate beans...

Comment: addes full stack trace. I cpould load these beans when I dont use Mockmvc

Comment: The root cause is clearly a `FileNotFoundException`. Your file isn't where you say it is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is spelled at the end of your stack trace:

> Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cache/ehcache-config.xml]

This most likely means that Spring's `MockServletContext` is not configured correctly.

Please note the Spring TestContext Framework creates a `MockServletContext` for your test's `ApplicationContext` whenever you annotate your test class with `@WebAppConfiguration`. Furthermore, the default resource path for `@WebAppConfiguration` is `file:src/main/webapp` (i.e., from the file system, not from the classpath).

But based on the paths that you pass to `@ContextConfiguration` in your example, you obviously have the `WEB-INF` folder in your classpath. So it appears that your project directory layout does not follow Maven standards for a web application.

To get your test working, you'll need to ensure that you properly configure the *root* of your web application with `@WebAppConfiguration`.

For example, if you insist on having your web artifacts in the classpath, you could do something like `@WebAppConfiguration("classpath:xyz")` where `xyz` is the folder in your classpath that serves as the root of your web application.

However, I would strongly recommend that you do **not** store all of your web artifacts in the classpath. You really should store web artifacts (including the `WEB-INF` folder) outside of the classpath. By "web artifacts" I mean things like HTML, CSS, JavaScript, images, JSPs, etc. But I do not mean that you have to store your Spring XML configuration files outside the classpath. I actually recommend that you store your Spring configuration files in the classpath (e.g., `src/main/resources` if following Maven's directory layout) and then reference them in the classpath (as you have done above but *without* storing them in a folder named `WEB-INF` in the classpath).

Hope this helps!

Sam

Comment: Sam, thanks for the detailed response. As I have mentioned before,

Comment: As you mentioned before... what exactly? ;)

Comment: I mean this configuratoon is working fine if I dont use MockMvc. My configuration files are able to load beans properly but as soon as I use @WebAppConfiguration, it is not able to load them and I get this error.

Comment: What do you mean by "[your] files are able to load beans properly"? Do you mean in production? Or do you mean in a test that loads the configuration differently?

Comment: "To get your test working, you'll need to ensure that you properly configure the root of your web application with @WebAppConfiguration." how do i do this?

Comment: @Sam Thanks for the detailed answer. I was working on a Eclipse Dynamic Web Project, so by putting `WebContent` worked exactly as you explained.